# Setting up name when registering

Tags: php, mysql, registration

All other functions are working on my registration page, the username, email, password are all working, but when they input a their name, it doesn't show in MySQL database.

[image: Here's my SQL Database Set up....]

There's my SQL database set up, am I setting up something wrong?

Here's my code for my registration page

```
<div class="login-box center">
            <div class="white-box">
                       <form class="form-horizontal m-t-20" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <h3>Sign Up</h3>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" required="" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group ">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input class="form-control" id="username" name="username" type="text" required="" placeholder="Username">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="text" required="" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password" type="password" required="" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input class="form-control" id="passwordConfirm" name="passwordConfirm" type="password" required="" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                                <input id="checkbox-signup" type="checkbox">
                                <label for="checkbox-signup"> By clicking Sign Up, you agree to our <a href="#">Terms</a> </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-center m-t-40">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-boom btn-login btn-lg btn-block text-uppercase waves-effect waves-light" name="submit" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Insert Code:

```
<?php require('includes/config.php');

//if logged in redirect to members page
if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: memberpage.php'); }

//if form has been submitted process it
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //very basic validation
    if(strlen($_POST['username']) < 3){
        $error[] = 'Username is too short.';
    } else {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT username FROM members WHERE username = :username');
        $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $_POST['username']));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(!empty($row['username'])){
            $error[] = 'Username provided is already in use.';
        }

    }

    if(strlen($_POST['password']) < 3){
        $error[] = 'Password is too short.';
    }

    if(strlen($_POST['passwordConfirm']) < 3){
        $error[] = 'Confirm password is too short.';
    }

    if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['passwordConfirm']){
        $error[] = 'Passwords do not match.';
    }

    //email validation
    if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $error[] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    } else {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT email FROM members WHERE email = :email');
        $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email']));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(!empty($row['email'])){
            $error[] = 'Email provided is already in use.';
        }

    }
```

Select:

```
       //Name Validation
    if(!filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $error[] = 'Please enter Your Name';
    } else {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT name FROM members WHERE name = :name');
        $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $_POST['name']));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


        }

    }


    //if no errors have been created carry on
    if(!isset($error)){

        //hash the password
        $hashedpassword = $user->password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        //create the activasion code
        $activasion = md5(uniqid(rand(),true));

        try {

            //insert into database with a prepared statement
            $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO members (name,username,password,email,active) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :active, :name)');
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':name' => $_POST['name'],
                ':username' => $_POST['username'],
                ':password' => $hashedpassword,
                ':email' => $_POST['email'],
                ':active' => $activasion
            ));
            $id = $db->lastInsertId('memberID');

            //send email
            $to = $_POST['email'];
            $subject = "Registration Confirmation";
            $body = "<p>Thank you for registering at BigFellaHQ.</p>
            <p>To activate your account, please click on this link: <a href='".DIR."activate.php?x=$id&y=$activasion'>".DIR."activate.php?x=$id&y=$activasion</a></p>
            <p>Regards BigFellaHQ Admin</p>";

            $mail = new Mail();
            $mail->setFrom(SITEEMAIL);
            $mail->addAddress($to);
            $mail->subject($subject);
            $mail->body($body);
            $mail->send();

            //redirect to index page
            header('Location: login.php?action=joined');
            exit;

        //else catch the exception and show the error.
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $error[] = $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Please provide your SQL `INSERT` statement. You might have problem there.

Comment: Where's the php code for registration page?

Comment: Looks like I forgot to add the Insert for mysql in my php

Comment: I only see selects and no insert

Comment: Added the Inserts into Database Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recheck columns and values in query you have :

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO members (name,username,password,email,active) 
                                   VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :active, :name)');
```

Comment: Figured it out. Thank You!

Comment: BigFella made small mistake!

Comment: Lol, Yup! I occasionally do that.